# Order by DESC is not working right anymore

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

Insert statement:

```
def PrincipalData():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("Principal.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS principal(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, CustomerID text, ServiceName text, ServicePrice text, Date text, Time text, ExtraProducts text, CustomerName text)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def addMainRec(CustomerID, ServiceName, ServicePrice, Date, Time, ExtraProducts, CustomerName ):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("Principal.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Principal VALUES (NULL, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (CustomerID, ServiceName, ServicePrice, Date, Time, ExtraProducts, CustomerName))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I have this sql query:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM principal ORDER BY Date DESC")
```

So I would like all the records from the principal table to be displayed from the highest Date to the lowest. And this line of code did that until it inexplicably broke.
This is my record list of what it currently does:

```
|15/02/2022| |14:05| |645321| |Abby| |N/A| |Woman's Haircut| |£21|
|17/02/2022| |12:55| |655769| |Anita| |N/A| |Haircut & dye| |£50|
|18/03/2022| |12:25| |124218| |Chloe| |Hair oil| |Haircut| |£45|
|13/02/2022| |12:45| |655769| |Jill| |N/A| |Afro| |£25|
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the datatype of column Date

Comment: Tag your question with the RDBMS you're using. The first thing to look at is whether the `Date` column is an *actual* date/time type, or a string.

Comment: I have defined the datatype as string, but it may be better to make it into date/time type

Comment: Tough luck. Use proper date data type, and it will work as expected.

Comment: And how would you define it as date/time as mine is currently "text"?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Most common, and SQL standard, is the data type `date`.)

Comment: @jarlh will give you correct answer, but I will recommend you to watch "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqnuwNc4-1M&ab_channel=ConnorMcDonald". It is not a answer to your question, but it might change your way of thinking for this particular case.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN, at the supermarket I choose the lane with the cutest cashier.

Comment: @jarlh, https://tenor.com/YaJ5.gif :).

Answer (score 0):

What does this do :

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM principal ORDER BY CAST("Date" AS DATE) DESC")
```

?

It's a ways to know if the "Date" columns (which is as stupid thing to name a column with a SQL keyword) is really a date or a text.

SQL is a typed language, not a spreadsheet  application like Excel !

Comment: It displays the entries in the order in which they were entered.  Would you like for me to show you the way in which the entries are added for a better understanding of what the code actually is?

Comment: Yes, please give INSERT SQL statement

Comment: Just have added the insert statement as well

Comment: so your date is not a date dataype it is a text...

Comment: I did try at as a date datatype with your example but I changed it back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS principal(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, CustomerID text, ServiceName text, ServicePrice text, Date text, Time text, ExtraProducts text, CustomerName text)
```

should by write as :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS principal(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, CustomerID text, ServiceName text, ServicePrice text, "Date" DATE, "Time" TIME, ExtraProducts text, CustomerName text)
```

In order to have an ORDER BY SQL clause operating as date ordering.

SQL is a strongly typed language with automatic transtyping...